# what is equivalent methods in C# for mark and reset methods in java

Tags: c#, java, stream

I am trying to convert a java class which extends BufferedInputStream class. It uses mark(1024) which I think it means the cursor will move to position 1024 and last it invokes reset() method. Now I have changed the class to inherit from BufferedStream in System.IO namespace, but I don't know whether there are equivalent methods for mark(int) and reset() methods in .net.

Comment: I think the `Seek` method and `Position` property are all you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.BufferedStream.aspx

Comment: you are right, I am going to test them.

Comment: Now I have used Seek(1024, SeekOrigin.Begin) instead of mark(1024). after a for and some code in the end of the java methods it calls reset(). do I need to set Position = 0 instead of rest() method?

Answer (score 0):

There are no equivalent methods in .NET. [`mark`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#mark%28int%29) marks the current position as the position `reset` should jump to.

But you can implement simplified versions of them yourself:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private int _resetPosition;

    public void Mark()
    {
        _resetPosition = Position;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Position = _resetPosition;
    }
}
```